# How to convert .mat file into .txt file containing a matrix of 1088 rows and 832 columns?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd like some help with my Matlab problem. I'm working on macOS with Matlab R2016b.  I want to convert a .mat file containing a matrix of 1088 rows and 832 columns into a .txt file.

I tried the above code without success.

```
load('H.mat')
dlmwrite('H.txt')
```

By loading the matrix on matlab I find the following informations :

[image: a]

Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify the matrix to be written onto the file: `dlmwrite('H.txt', H)`

Comment: Thanks Lui mendo, I've tried your code but I'm finding this error :                 `Undefined function 'real' for input arguments of type 'struct'.`
`Error in dlmwrite (line 189)`
 `str = sprintf('%.*g%+.*gi',precn,real(m(i,j)),precn,imag(m(i,j)));`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize `H` is a field of a `struct` variable called `code`.  Try `dlmwrite('H.txt', code.H)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dlmwrite is not [recommended by matlab](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html?searchHighlight=dlmwrite&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#mw_50bcd562-2d7b-4082-b38f-7220e91e3cc7):
Better use

```
load('H.mat')
writematrix(H, 'H.txt')
```

see [writematrix](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks BitLaucher, I've tried your code but I'm finding this error : `Undefined function or variable 'writematrix'.`

Comment: The `writematrix` function is only present in recent Matlab versions

Comment: I've installed matlab 2019 and it works, thank you.